# Playframework typesafe reactive-scales template request per second remains at 140

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

When I tried typesafe reactive-scales template for load testing as given in in demo http://go.typesafe.com/scalability/show-off 
request per second remains at 120-130. Demo shows it above 25000.
What could be the reason?. 
I am using quad core machine running windows 7. Available Memory is 12GB.

Comment: How is your thread pool configured? The thread pool might influence the performance. (-> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools )

Comment: Hadn't seen it before, tried it out, had to tweak it a bit to get it to run, but on my recent MBP it does ~54000 reqs/s. Do you maybe have anything else heavy running simultaneously, copying big files, downloading something, firewall intercepting each request etc?

Comment: And ~10 000 reqs/s inside of a virtual machine with windows 7 on the same laptop (given 1Gb ram and two cores). So, nothing obvious broken with running it on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received a reply from james(http://www.jamesward.com/) that it could be a windows issue.

> The other possibility is that this is a Windows issue.  I vaguely remember Play at one point not performing well on Windows due to something in the underlying networking stack.  I'm not sure if this was fixed in newer versions.

When tested in EC2 on linux machine we got request per second in 20-25K range.

Thanks every one.